# rails - how to add Quantity text_field to Products list in Shopping Cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopping-cart

I'm building Simple Shopping Cart solution for the purpose of practicing so that I don't want to use gems (e.g. spree).

There is a **products list** page. By the side of each product, there is **add to cart** button.

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product), remote: true %>
```

This button will go to **line_items_controller#create** method. Simply the line item will be created or increased by one.

```
  def create
    session[:counter] = 0

    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id) # @cart is actually Cart Model

    ...
  end
```

My question is how would I add **Quantity text_field** beside of add to cart button in the products list page. This **Quantity text_field** will also be posted to **line_items_controller#create** method but the line item will be created with this quantity.

I confuse that if I use form helper, which model object do I need to reference in this situation. Is there any other ways to add text_field without using form_helpers?

Can you suggest the best way to solve this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [text_field_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag)

Add this to your form:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'quantity' %>
```

Then access `quantity` as a parameter in your create action:

```
quantity = params[:quantity]
```

Make sure to whitelist the `quantity` parameter. In Rails 4:

```
def line_item_params
   params.require(:line_item).permit(:quantity)
end
```

Comment: Your suggested solution resolve my problem. For additional information, it needs to use form_tag instead of form_for for using text_field_tag.